# CombinedError: [GraphQL] Experience with id doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, expo, eas

I am using dynamic configuration for my expo app and it seems that, that's causing some problem when trying to `expo build`. I have linked the expo project correctly to the eas project and upon running any command that start with `expo build` I am thrown the following error :

`CombinedError: [GraphQL] Experience with id 'xxx-1xxx-4xxx-bx-baxxxfc' does not exist.`

I suspect my app.config.json is the problem but I have no idea on how to fix it

```
import "dotenv/config";

export default {
  expo: {
    name: "LetsChat",
    slug: "LetsChat",
    version: "1.0.0",
    scheme: "com.bertdelaspeed.letschat",
    orientation: "portrait",
    icon: "./assets/icon.png",
    userInterfaceStyle: "light",
    splash: {
      image: "./assets/splash.png",
      resizeMode: "contain",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    },
    updates: {
      fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0,
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: ["**/*"],
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: true,
    },
    android: {
      package: "com.bertdelaspeed.letschat",
      googleServicesFile: "./google-services.json",
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      },
    },
    web: {
      favicon: "./assets/favicon.png",
    },
    extra: {
      apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
      authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
      projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
      messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
      appId: process.env.APP_ID,
      measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID,
      eas: {
        projectId: "xxx-1xxx-4xxx-bx-baxxxfc",
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          photosPermission:
            "The app accesses your photos to let you share them with your friends.",
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You may need to change the **project id** field in your app.json under extra.eas.projectId - it appears to somehow be set to an incorrect value

You will get the **product id** from app.json under **Extra** --> **eas**  --> **ProjectID**

[image]

Comment: This is useful, especially if you find+replace a version id and that id happens to be part of the projectID like I just did.